# Merge two arrays with input fields together

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, foreach

I'd like to merge two arrays together. I know that there is $.merge but this doesn't work.

Here are my arrays:

```
S (1)
0 S (2)
    <input type="text" name="f_name">
    <input type="text" name="l_name">
1 S (2)
    <input type="text" name="f_name">
    <input type="text" name="l_name">
```

How can I combine them so the result is:

```
0 S (4)
    <input type="text" name="f_name">
    <input type="text" name="l_name">
    <input type="text" name="f_name">
    <input type="text" name="l_name">
```

PS: I got the first array using

```
selected.forEach((a, i) => {
  arr[i] = a.map(function() {
    return $(this).find('input');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.flat()` method.
See following example, if `depth` is unknown you can specify `Infinity`.

```js
const input = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
const flattenedArr = input.flat(3);
console.log(flattenedArr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your anser. But it seems that this doesn't work for selected element. Or am I doing something wrong? I just added arr.flat(2) to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat(...)` method. as the following e.g.

```js
var arr1 = [0, 1, 2];
var arr2 = [3, 4, 5];
var All = arr1.concat(arr2); 
console.log(All)
```